# Why "=" and "like" work in the same statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I was practicing SQL injection skill, and I found that I could put `=` and `LIKE` in a single statement.

However, I'm not sure what does this mean and why it works?

```
SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE name='' LIKE '%'
```

So, what does that mean when I put `=` and `LIKE` in a statement, and when would I write something like this?

Comment: Which database system?

Comment: @scaisEdge for MySql is syntactically correct (logically not).

Comment: @scaisEdge `name='' LIKE '%'` evaluates to `name=('' LIKE '%')` or `name=1`

Comment: This is invalid (standard) SQL Any self-respecting DBMS will reject that

Comment: OK, I put the type of database in the tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you are using MySQL, because this is syntactically correct in MySQL.  It treats boolean types as numbers (which will be converted to integers and strings).

So, your code should be parsed as:

```
WHERE (name = '') LIKE '%'
```

This is because `=` and `LIKE` have the same precedence, and when operators have the same precedence, they are evaluated left-to-right (as explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html)).

This, in turn evaluates to one of these three possibilities:

```
WHERE 1 LIKE '%'   -- when name = ''
WHERE 0 LIKE '%'   -- otherwise when name is not null
WHERE NULL like '%'
```

The first two will always evaluate to true.  The third would discard any row where `name` is `null`.

Comment: I did not downvote your question. But the order of parsing is different. It is: `name = ('' LIKE '%')`. I tested it.

Comment: @forpas . . . That is interesting.  According to the documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html), `=` and `like` have the  same precedence.  Hence, they should be evaluated left-to-right.  If your tests show something different, that is a bug in MySQL (or the documentation).

Comment: I thought so too. But: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=506b2b5b156e9f65e4745bc9252cc133

Comment: @forpas . . . .That looks like a bug.  I did revise the answer to add "should" and reference the documentation.

Comment: And the expression is parsed as expected: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pjCiZRRdMkvbJ3FhzGNetx/0

Answer (score -2):

(in MySQL and other popular DBMS) The LIKE operator is used to search for a specified pattern in a column. It admits "%" as a wildcard that represents zero, one, or multiple characters.

Your query always passes because the string '' meets this wildcard (zero characters). Incidentally, almost anything will. Some DBMS will react differently to such a query though.

Comment: . . Personally, I find that offensive.  I'm the only other person with an answer, so it would seem to be directed at me, and this is definitely not something that I would ever do -- even when, as now, I am offended.

Comment: Your answer is not useful because it doesn't address OP's question.